# Tallying Unique Names per month using in cell formulas

Tags: arrays, excel, excel-formula

I have a list of people and dates that they were contacted.  From that list, I need to pull the number of contacts per month for unique individuals.  Here's an example list:

[image]

I need a formula in D:D that returns a 1 for the first instance of a date for each unique individual.  I really don't want to manually type all those 1's.

I'll update this with what I come up with - I usually like to show that I've made an attempt, but I'm really not familiar with arrays at all, and I'm sure I'm going to need one here.

I appreciate the assistance, thanks.

Comment: I don't really understand the question. From your screenshot, looks like you want the column to return `1` for the first instance of a date in a particular month occurring for a particular individual (and return blank otherwise). Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.  I'll clarify in the post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using your provided sample data, in cell C2 and copy down, no array needed:

```
=IF(COUNTIFS(A$2:A2,A2,B$2:B2,">="&DATE(YEAR(B2),MONTH(B2),1),B$2:B2,"<"&EOMONTH(B2,0)+1)=1,1,"")
```

Alternate:

```
=IF(COUNTIFS(A$2:A2,A2,B$2:B2,">="&EOMONTH(B2,-1)+1,B$2:B2,"<"&EOMONTH(B2,0)+1)=1,1,"")
```

Comment: Thank you so much!  One question about this: if the list of names were to be scrambled instead of alphabetical, would this formula still work?

Comment: @DustinBurns It should, yes.

Comment: I'm attempting to modify the formula you've provided above to add another criteria.  I've made this simple change:

=IF(COUNTIFS(F3, "S", B$3:B3,B3,D$3:D3,">="&DATE(YEAR(D3),MONTH(D3),1),D$3:D3,"<"&EOMONTH(D3,0)+1)=1,1,"")

and now I'm getting a #VALUE error when I copy down.  I'm confused by this, because for every cell where the value in F equals "S", the countifs should return true.  Otherwise, it should return false.  I'm not sure where my error in logic is.

Comment: @DustinBurns Your range needs to be a range, not just a single cell.  Should be `...F$3:F3,"S"...`